# How can I filter .content from a invoke-webrequest command

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, invoke-webrequest

I have an internal web app that provides connection statistics. I am trying to use PS to collect those statistics, which are in .conent. The .content property has a lot of other values I am trying to filter out and I haven't been very successful.

My Command:

```bsh
invoke-webrequest -URI http://<my internal web site> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
```

Returned Results:

```
Greetings from live node:  server-name [ FQDN ] , serving at port: 443 since [4 days, 0 hour, 3
3 minutes, 33 seconds] with following settings:

IN_MEMORY_MESSAGE_LIFE_IN_HOURS : 1
DELIVERY_GRACE_WINDOW_IN_SECONDS : 10
BUILD_NUMBER : 4
STATISTICS_LOG_FREQUENCY_IN_MINUTES : 0
HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES : 2
CLUSTERING_MODE : IMPLICIT
CLEAN_ORPHANED_SESSIONS : Y
OFFLOAD_SSL : Y
SERVICE_HOST : 192.168.1.1
REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MILLIS : 3000
SERVICE_PORT : 443
VALIDATE_REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE : N
APP_BROADCAST_LIFE_IN_MINUTES : 1
DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LIFE_IN_DAYS : 1
VERSION : release/2008
ENABLE_IDLER_STATISTICS : Y
ORIGIN_STATS_EXPIRY_IN_MINUTES : 60
INCLUDE_CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER_IN_HEALTH_CHECK : N
DATABASE_PROVIDER : INMEMORY
QUEUEMONITOR_THREADPOOLSIZE : 100
BUILD_DATE : Mon 27 Jul 2020 10:02:44 AM EDT -0400
BUILD_PLAN : AWCM-AWCM302-JOB1-4

Persistence Store Type:INMEMORY , status: live

Current Active Sessions: 6
```

They only line I care about is "Current Active Sessions: 6" and really all I care about is the numerical value which I will use in a test later in the script.

How can I just grab the one value I need?

Comment: My entire output was converted in a single string. I had to use -split to break the output into single lines which let me filter on the line I wanted

Comment: $iwr=invoke-webrequest -URI http://<my internal web site> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content

Comment: $iwr.split("`n") | Select-String -Pattern "Current Active Sessions: (.*)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$iwr=invoke-webrequest -URI http://<my internal web site> |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
$cas=$iwr -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    Select-String -Pattern "Current Active Sessions:\s*(.*)"
$cas.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

Above code snippet should return `6`. Tested using the following (constant) value of `$iwr` instead of `invoke-webrequest`:

```
$iwr=@'
Greetings from live node:  server-name [ FQDN ] , serving at port: 443 since [4 days, 0 hour, 3
3 minutes, 33 seconds] with following settings:

IN_MEMORY_MESSAGE_LIFE_IN_HOURS : 1
DELIVERY_GRACE_WINDOW_IN_SECONDS : 10
BUILD_NUMBER : 4
STATISTICS_LOG_FREQUENCY_IN_MINUTES : 0
HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES : 2
CLUSTERING_MODE : IMPLICIT
CLEAN_ORPHANED_SESSIONS : Y
OFFLOAD_SSL : Y
SERVICE_HOST : 192.168.1.1
REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MILLIS : 3000
SERVICE_PORT : 443
VALIDATE_REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE : N
APP_BROADCAST_LIFE_IN_MINUTES : 1
DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LIFE_IN_DAYS : 1
VERSION : release/2008
ENABLE_IDLER_STATISTICS : Y
ORIGIN_STATS_EXPIRY_IN_MINUTES : 60
INCLUDE_CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER_IN_HEALTH_CHECK : N
DATABASE_PROVIDER : INMEMORY
QUEUEMONITOR_THREADPOOLSIZE : 100
BUILD_DATE : Mon 27 Jul 2020 10:02:44 AM EDT -0400
BUILD_PLAN : AWCM-AWCM302-JOB1-4

Persistence Store Type:INMEMORY , status: live

Current Active Sessions: 6
'@
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$iwr=invoke-webrequest -URI http://<my internal web site> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
$iwr|Select-String -Pattern "Current Active Sessions: (.*)"
```

Comment: Thanks Wasif. Unfortunately the output is the same

Comment: It appears the entire output in $iwr is seen as one whole string. If the pattern does not match then I don't see anything